# SQL LISTAGG for different types of values

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I have the following table

```
name   type            value 

a      mobile          123456  
a      home tel        456789  
a      Office addr     add1  
a      home addr       add2  
b      mobile          456456  
b      home tel        123123  
b      Office addr     add3  
b      home addr       add4
```

I want to make an SQL table like this

```
name    phone             address

a       123456; 456789    add1; add2  
b       456456; 123123    add3; add4
```

I tried this SQL:

```
SELECT name, 
LISTAGG(t.CONTACT_INFO,';')
               WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY type) AS phone where type in ('mobile', 'home tel'),
LISTAGG(t.CONTACT_INFO,';')
               WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY type) AS address where type in ('Office addr', 'home addr')
FROM table t
  GROUP BY name
```

And it doesn't work. I know because the WHERE clause is not where it needs to be. But where can I insert the restrictions? If I do it like

```
SELECT name, 
LISTAGG(t.CONTACT_INFO,';')
               WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY type) AS phone,
LISTAGG(t.CONTACT_INFO,';')
               WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY type) AS address
FROM table t
  GROUP BY name
```

It would look like

```
name    phone                         address

a       123456; 456789;add1; add2     123456; 456789;add1; add2  
b       456456; 123123;add3; add4     456456; 123123;add3; add4
```

Answer (score 0):

may be something like this, but i think you DB design is very bad

```
with a(name,type,value ) as (select 'a','mobile','123456' from dual union all
                             select 'a','home tel','456789' from dual union all
                             select 'a','Office addr', 'add1' from dual union all
                             select 'a','home addr','add2' from dual union all
                             select 'b','mobile','456456' from dual union all
                             select 'b','home tel','123123' from dual union all
                             select 'b','Office addr','add3' from dual union all
                             select 'b','home addr', 'add4' from dual  )
select a1.name,
       Listagg(a1.value, ';') Within Group (order by a1.type desc) phone,
       Listagg(a2.value, ';') Within Group (order by a2.type) address
  from a a1 inner join a a2 
        on decode(a1.type,'mobile','Office addr','home tel','home addr') = a2.type and a1.name = a2.name
group by a1.name
```

output is:

```
a   123456;456789   add1;add2
b   456456;123123   add3;add4
```

Answer (score 0):

if order phone numbers (mobile, home) are not important
Try this code block:

```
select t2.name
      ,listagg(t2.phone
              ,';') within group(order by t2.phone) as phone
      ,listagg(t2.addresss
              ,';') within group(order by t2.addresss) as addresss
  from (select t.name
              ,case
                 when t.type in ('mobile'
                                ,'home tel') then
                  listagg(t.value
                         ,';') within group(order by t.type)
                 else
                  null
               end as phone
              ,case
                 when t.type in ('Office addr'
                                ,'home addr') then
                  listagg(t.value
                         ,';') within group(order by t.type)
                 else
                  null
               end as addresss
          from table t
         group by t.name
                 ,t.type) t2
 group by t2.name
```

Give this result:

```
 a   123456;456789   add1;add2
 b   123123;456456   add3;add4
```